# Why does this weird "content" attribute has no file associated with it error comes up in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

This question might have been asked several times before but I referred to them but I was not able to fix my problem. That is why I am having to ask it. So, I have a Django app where users can set up tasks. They can also upload attachments. I was successfully able to implement this but for some reason it has stopped working now. These are the relevant code:

models.py

```
def get_attachment_dir(instance, filename):
    return f"users/{instance.parent_task.creator.username}_{instance.parent_task.creator.pk}/task_attachments/{instance.parent_task.pk}/{filename}"


class Attachments(models.Model):
    content = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=get_attachment_dir, help_text="Add important documents or pictures")
    parent_task = models.ForeignKey(ToDo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    uploaded_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Attachments of {self.parent_task.title}"
```

forms.py

```
class TaskAttachmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Attachments
        fields = ["content"]
```

Relevant part of the view function that renders the attachment form

```
    if request.method == "POST":

        attachment_form = TaskAttachmentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if attachment_form.is_valid():
            # Making sure we get no Integrity Errors
            attachment_form.instance.parent_task = todo
            attachment_form.save()

            if not todo.has_attachments:
                todo.has_attachments = True
                todo.save()

            messages.success(request, "Your files were uploaded successfully")

    else:
        attachment_form = TaskAttachmentForm()

    attachments = Attachments.objects.filter(parent_task=todo)

    context = {
        "todo": todo,
        "note_form": ToDoNotesForm(),
        "note": note,
        "subtask_form": SubTaskForm(),
        "attachment_form": attachment_form,
        "subtasks": subtasks,
        "due_form": DueDateForm(),
        "title": todo.title,
        "percentage": percentage,
        "attachments": attachments
    }

    return render(request, "ToDo/detailed_view.html", context=context)
```

detailed_view.html relevant code where attachments are handled

```
{% if attachments %}
    <div id="attachments-section" class="table-responsive dark-mode-assist-section">          
        <table class="table dark-mode-assist-section">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>File</th>
                    <th>Uploaded on</th>
                    <th>View/Download</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for attachment in attachments %}
                    <tr class="list-group-item" id="attachment-{{ attachment.pk }}">
                        <td>{{ attachment.content|getfilename }}</td>
                        <td>{{ attachment.uploaded_on|date:"F d"}}</td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ attachment.content.url }}">Click me</a></td>
                        <td>
                            <button style="font-size: 2.5ch;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter{{ attachment.pk }}" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter{{ attachment.pk }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                    aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content dark-mode-assist-section">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Confirm the deletion</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    Are you sure you want to delete this attachment?
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button data-dismiss="modal" onclick="deleteItem('attachment', {{ attachment.pk }})" type="submit"
                                        class="btn btn-danger">Yes, I am sure</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    <a class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample-attachments" role="button"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample">
        Upload attachments
    </a>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample-attachments">
                <br>
                <div class="card card-body dark-mode-assist-section">
                    <div class="content section">
                        <form method="POST" name="attachment-{{ todo.pk }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <fieldset class="form-group dark-mode-assist">
                                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Add documents</legend>
                                {{ attachment_form|crispy }}
                                <input type="hidden" name="title" value={{ todo.pk }}>
                                <p id="hidden-parent-task-pk" style="display:none">{{ todo.pk }}</p>
                            </fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-upload"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>i
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am saying that this seems weird is because I was able to access `attachment.content` when running the same command under `python manage.py shell`

Any help is seriously appreciated and needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you verified the "content" path is saved to the DB. You can run a quick `SELECT * FROM <insert table name> WHERE 'id' = <insert the ID of an attatchment>`. If the path exists in the DB, the problem is in the retrieval. If it does not exist the problem is in the saving process.

Comment: Because `content` can be `None` (`NULL`)?

Comment: are files are uploaded successfully ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. The files were actually uploaded and saved in their respective directories. But I still had the issue. Willem was right about the `None` part. One of the attachments were `None` which caused the issue. I deleted this from the db and now everything works smoothly